# How do I match XML tags multiple times with regexp in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, xml, string-matching

I have the following XML document, which represents an API call from a bus stop:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfPolling xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Polling>
    <id>1494</id>
    <name>Street xyz</name>
    <time>14.08</time>
    <line>AB2</line>
    <timeMin>5</timeMin>
  </Polling>
  <Polling>
    <id>1494</id>
    <name>Street xyz</name>
    <time>14.10</time>
    <line>140</line>
    <timeMin>7</timeMin>
  </Polling>
  <Polling>
    <id>1494</id>
    <name>Street xyz</name>
    <time>14.12</time>
    <line>AB2</line>
    <timeMin>9</timeMin>
  </Polling>
  <Polling>
    <id>1494</id>
    <name>Street xyz</name>
    <time>14.15</time>
    <line>140</line>
    <timeMin>12</timeMin>
  </Polling>
</ArrayOfPolling>
```

I need to fetch this info in pure JavaScript, no jQuery, no xml2json, etc.
So I chose to proceed with `match()`, but I don't know much about regular expressions. I tried for example with `<name>(.+?)<\/name>,<line>(.+?)<\/line>`, etc. but I don't know how to iterate and put everything inside an array.

Could you shed some lights on me?

Comment: Do you need to parse any kind of XML file? Or do you need to parse only this particular case?

Comment: this particular case. but i need iteration because <Polling> tag number can vary.

Comment: Javascript vector == a regular array? an object?

Comment: yep, sorry, wrong terminology. regular array.

Comment: Is the order of individual elements fixed, or could there be some missing or in another order? Can you add a manually created example output? For the record: your attempts with `match` probably failed because this is multiline input. You can safely remove the hard returns before processing any further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var re = /<id>(.+?)<\/id>|<name>(.+?)<\/name>|<time>(.+?)<\/time>|<line>(.+?)<\/line>|<timeMin>(.+?)<\/timeMin>/g; 
    var str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n<ArrayOfPolling xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">\n  <Polling>\n    <id>1494</id>\n    <name>Street xyz</name>\n    <time>14.08</time>\n    <line>AB2</line>\n    <timeMin>5</timeMin>\n  </Polling>\n  <Polling>\n    <id>1494</id>\n    <name>Street xyz</name>\n    <time>14.10</time>\n    <line>140</line>\n    <timeMin>7</timeMin>\n  </Polling>\n  <Polling>\n    <id>1494</id>\n    <name>Street xyz</name>\n    <time>14.12</time>\n    <line>AB2</line>\n    <timeMin>9</timeMin>\n  </Polling>\n  <Polling>\n    <id>1494</id>\n    <name>Street xyz</name>\n    <time>14.15</time>\n    <line>140</line>\n    <timeMin>12</timeMin>\n  </Polling>\n</ArrayOfPolling>';
    var m;
    var result ="";
    
    while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
        if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
            re.lastIndex++;
        }
        // View your result using the m-variable.
        // eg m[0] etc.
        if(undefined != m[1]) result += "id: " + m[1] + "</br>";
        if(undefined != m[2]) result += "name: " + m[2] + "</br>";
        if(undefined != m[3]) result +=  "time: " + m[3] + "</br>";
        if(undefined != m[4]) result += "line: " + m[4] + "</br>";
        if(undefined != m[5]) result += "timeMin: " + m[5] + "</br>";
        
    }
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div id="results"></div>
```

You can use that (it only prints, you can alternatively stores in an array):

```js
var re = /<id>(.+?)<\/id>|<name>(.+?)<\/name>|<time>(.+?)<\/time>|<line>(.+?)<\/line>|<timeMin>(.+?)<\/timeMin>/g; 
var str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n<ArrayOfPolling xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">\n  <Polling>\n    <id>1494</id>\n    <name>Street xyz</name>\n    <time>14.08</time>\n    <line>AB2</line>\n    <timeMin>5</timeMin>\n  </Polling>\n  <Polling>\n    <id>1494</id>\n    <name>Street xyz</name>\n    <time>14.10</time>\n    <line>140</line>\n    <timeMin>7</timeMin>\n  </Polling>\n  <Polling>\n    <id>1494</id>\n    <name>Street xyz</name>\n    <time>14.12</time>\n    <line>AB2</line>\n    <timeMin>9</timeMin>\n  </Polling>\n  <Polling>\n    <id>1494</id>\n    <name>Street xyz</name>\n    <time>14.15</time>\n    <line>140</line>\n    <timeMin>12</timeMin>\n  </Polling>\n</ArrayOfPolling>';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
    if(undefined != m[1]) console.log("id: " + m[1]);
    if(undefined != m[2]) console.log("name: " + m[2]);
    if(undefined != m[3]) console.log("time: " + m[3]);
    if(undefined != m[4]) console.log("line: " + m[4]);
    if(undefined != m[5]) console.log("timeMin: " + m[5]);
}
```

Output:

```
id: 1494
name: Street xyz
time: 14.08
line: AB2
timeMin: 5
id: 1494
name: Street xyz
time: 14.10
line: 140
timeMin: 7
id: 1494
name: Street xyz
time: 14.12
line: AB2
timeMin: 9
id: 1494
name: Street xyz
time: 14.15
line: 140
timeMin: 12
```

[DEMO - RegExp](https://regex101.com/r/bF9wD3/1)

[DEMO - js](http://jsfiddle.net/hjdzxskd/)

Basically you will select for each iteration the element that was matched using capture groups